# Independence of past and future states in Markov Chains

Tags: probability, probability-theory, markov-chains, independence

I have seen this statement in a quiz:

> Let $X_i$ denote state $i$ in a Markov chain. It is necessarily true
>   that $X_{i+1}$ and $X_{i-1}$ are uncorrelated.

Apparently, this statement is **false** but I can't figure out why. I thought that for Markov Chains the **past and future states** are independent **given the present**. Did I misunderstand this?

Comment: The Markov property basically says that you never have to condition on more than the last known state, not that states more than two ticks apart are independent. If they were, why would we ever care about the starting state of the process?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The key phrase is "given the present". If past and future are independent given the present, it doesn't follow that past and future are unconditionally independent.

For example, consider the simple random walk that takes a step either left or right with equal probability. If you know where I am today, then the knowledge of where I was yesterday won't affect where you think I'll be tomorrow. OTOH if you *don't* know where I am today, then knowing where I was yesterday will affect where you think I will be tomorrow, since tomorrow I can be at most two steps away from where I was yesterday.

Comment: So the past and the future of a state can be correlated if I don't consider the present state?

Comment: @arifCee Correct, if you have no knowledge of the present state, then past and future can be correlated. In symbols: $P(X_{n-1}\in A, X_{n+1}\in  B)$ is not necessarily equal to $P(X_{n-1}\in A)P(X_{n+1}\in B)$. Notice that these two quantities do not involve conditional probabilities.

Answer (score 2):

Conditioned on $X_i$, $X_{i+1}$ and $X_{i-1}$ are indeed uncorrelated (and actually are much stronger: they are independent; you can check this).

However, think of the following chain: $X_n = B$ where $B$ is some Bernoulli random variable. You can check this is Markov (If I tell you the state $X_{n-1}$, I told you what $X_n$ is so no need to further condition) Note that $X_i = X_j$ for any $i,j$, and these are clearly positively correlated!.